# Javascript problems with click events

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make sure that when a certain element is clicked all the others are closed.

The only way this currently works is if you close and open the popups by clicking the same `li` twice.

[Example Here](http://xch07.wi2.sde.dk/sandbox/toggleTest/index.php)

## Problem 01

When I click and close the popup via `#overlay`, the `#overlay` will switch the class. How do I target the correct popup and close that as well?

## Problem 02

When I open the popup by clicking the first `li` and then click another `li` the whole order is screwing up (because it does not close the last one).

```js
function changeClass(element, remove, add) {
  if (element.classList.contains(remove)) {
    element.classList.remove(remove);
    element.classList.add(add);
  } else if (element.classList.contains(add)) {
    element.classList.remove(add);
    element.classList.add(remove);
  }
}

function hasClass(element, cls) {
  return element.classList.contains(cls);
}

var overlay = document.querySelector("#overlay")
var leftNavModal = document.querySelector("#leftNavModal");
var options = document.querySelectorAll(".options");
options.forEach(function(c) {
  let target = c;
  c.addEventListener("click", function(d) {
    var div = document.querySelector(this.getAttribute("data-div")); // ***
    changeClass(overlay, "displayn", "displayb")
    changeClass(div, "displayb", "displayn");
    //TAGER FAT I DATA ATTRIBUTEN SOM SELECTOR TIL DIV'EN ID
  }, false);
});
var option = document.querySelector("#option");
window.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  if (event.target === overlay || event.target === option) {
    var div = document.querySelectorAll("popUp");
    overlay.style.display = "none";

    var div = document.querySelectorAll("popUp");

  };
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#container {
  display: flex;
}

#navigation {
  width: 20vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: red;
}

#navigation ul li {
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#content {
  width: 80vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: blue;
  position: relative;
}

.displayn {
  display: none;
}

.displayb {
  display: block;
}

.leftNavModal {
  padding: 15px;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  position: absolute;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  background-color: #fff;
}

#overlay {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="navigation">
    <ul class="col100 leftLinkWrapper overflowh ">
      <li data-div="#id01" class="options displayb pad20 bgcg pointer">Random 01</li>
      <li data-div="#id02" class="options displayb pad20 bgcg pointer">Random 02</li>
      <li data-div="#id03" class="options displayb pad20 bgcg pointer">Random 03</li>
      <li data-div="#id04" class="options displayb pad20 bgcg pointer">Random 04</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="content">
    <div id="overlay" class="displayn">
      <div id="leftNavModal" class="leftNavModal">
        <div id="id01" class="popUp displayn">01 - Some say this is random</div>
        <div id="id02" class="popUp displayn">02 - This is not that random</div>
        <div id="id03" class="popUp displayn">03 - So what is random</div>
        <div id="id04" class="popUp displayn">04 - Nothing is</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: 1. Why don't you use jQuery? 2. About second problem: just add then at the begin simple (in pseudocode): ``if (it's open) then close``. After that code which you have – opening ;)

Comment: I am trying to solve it without the use of jQery :)

Comment: Well... that's good reason :D

Comment: It looks like a scope problem. Try putting the contents of forEach inside (function(){ /* Your code here */ }())

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, first of all so you should organize your code better but trying to modify your code the less possible here it goes!

So get all the pops outside the event (just to make it more efficient). Then iterate through the elements comparing the ids, if the id does not correspond to one clicked then set it ot be hidden else show it. Basically you have to iterate through each element! The window event handles the situations where neither the option nor the overlay is clicked!

```js
function changeClass(element, remove, add) {
  if (element.classList.contains(remove)) {
    element.classList.remove(remove);
    element.classList.add(add);
  } else if (element.classList.contains(add)) {
    element.classList.remove(add);
    element.classList.add(remove);
  }
}

function hasClass(element, cls) {
  return element.classList.contains(cls);
}

var overlay = document.querySelector("#overlay")
var leftNavModal = document.querySelector("#leftNavModal");
var options = document.querySelectorAll(".options");
var pops = document.querySelectorAll(".popUp");

options.forEach(function(c) {
  let target = c;
  c.addEventListener("click", function(d) {
    var id = this.getAttribute("data-div"); // ***
    pops.forEach(function(x){
      x.style.display = x.id !== id ? "none" : "block";
    });
  }, false);
});
var option = document.querySelector("#option");
window.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  
  overlay.style.display = !event.target.classList.contains("options") &&            !event.target.classList.contains("overlay") ? "none" : "block";
 
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#container {
  display: flex;
}

#navigation {
  width: 20vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: red;
}

#navigation ul li {
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#content {
  width: 80vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: blue;
  position: relative;
}

.displayn {
  display: none;
}

.displayb {
  display: block;
}

.leftNavModal {
  padding: 15px;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  position: absolute;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  background-color: #fff;
}

#overlay {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="navigation">
    <ul class="col100 leftLinkWrapper overflowh ">
      <li data-div="id01" class="options displayb pad20 bgcg pointer">Random 01</li>
      <li data-div="id02" class="options displayb pad20 bgcg pointer">Random 02</li>
      <li data-div="id03" class="options displayb pad20 bgcg pointer">Random 03</li>
      <li data-div="id04" class="options displayb pad20 bgcg pointer">Random 04</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="content">
    <div id="overlay" class="displayn">
      <div id="leftNavModal" class="leftNavModal">
        <div id="id01" class="popUp displayn">01 - Some say this is random</div>
        <div id="id02" class="popUp displayn">02 - This is not that random</div>
        <div id="id03" class="popUp displayn">03 - So what is random</div>
        <div id="id04" class="popUp displayn">04 - Nothing is</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation of why/how this code helps the OP. This will help provide an answer future viewers can learn from. See [this Meta question and its answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/256359/215552) for more information.